# Change label content when click a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want a `StackPanel` with dynamically added buttons that update a label content when clicked. I use `Button.Click="ChildsButtonClick"` to assign the event from the `StackPanel` to it's children and update the label content. But, is it possible to do it only with `XAML` and `Bindings`, `Triggers`, etc..? As you suppose I'm new to this world.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Height="165"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="465"
                Button.Click="ChildsButtonClick">
        <Button x:Name="button"
                Content="Button1"
                d:LayoutOverrides="Height" />
        <Button x:Name="button1"
                Content="Button2"
                d:LayoutOverrides="Height" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Label x:Name="label"
           Content="Label"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Margin="0,195,0,0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

CS:

```
private void ChildsButtonClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button a = e.Source as Button;
        if (a != null)
        {
            label.Content = a.Content;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to do this without the event?

Comment: You need to trigger an event to make it do something, otherwise you won't do anything -.-

Comment: The buttons can't update a new property on the windows with a trigger, that is binded to the label.content?

Comment: Bottom line. You want to click a button. That is an event. No event, no changes.

Comment: If you want to use data binding, you have to bind label's content with a string property that returns the content of a button.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. Uses no events in code behind. Not sure if it will help you or not, but you may be able to work it to fit.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="Button">
              <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="label" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Content"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
              </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
  </Grid.Triggers>
        <DockPanel>
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="label">Hi</Label>
        <Button x:Name="Button" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="50" Width="50">

        </Button>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
```